# Near identical functions, yet only some give divide by 0 errors

Tags: c, divide-by-zero

Was given a function to do simple matrix-matrix element-wise division. However, running the int8 & int16 versions return Integer divide by 0 errors from valgrind, & seg faults from command line. The int32, spfp and dpfp functions, which I ensured were the same text besides type declaration, do not have this problem. The values in the matrix are randomly genrated with the rand() function. Why would only some of these return divide by 0 errors?

First Function

```
double matrix_matrix_div_elementwise_int8(int size,int threads)
{
//initialize index variables, random number generator, and timer
int i;
int size2D=size*size;
srand(SEED);
struct TIME_STRUCT start,end;

//allocate memory for matrices
INT8_TYPE *A=malloc(sizeof(INT8_TYPE)*(size*size));
INT8_TYPE *B=malloc(sizeof(INT8_TYPE)*(size*size));
INT8_TYPE *C=malloc(sizeof(INT8_TYPE)*(size*size));

//initialize input matrices to random numbers
//initialize output matrix to zeros
for(i=0;i<(size*size);i++)
{
    A[i]=rand();
    B[i]=rand();
    C[i]=0;
}

//serial operation
if(threads==1)
{
    //start timer
    TIME_GET(&start);
    //computation
    for(i=0;i<size2D;i++)
    {
        C[i]=A[i]/B[i];
    }
    //end timer
    TIME_GET(&end);
}
//parallel operation
else
{
    //start timer
    TIME_GET(&start);
    //parallelize with OpenMP
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads) private(i)
    //computation
    for(i=0;i<size2D;i++)
    {
        C[i]=A[i]/B[i];
    }
    //end timer
    TIME_GET(&end);
}

//free memory
free(C);
free(B);
free(A);

return TIME_RUNTIME(start,end);
}
```

Second Function

```
double matrix_matrix_div_elementwise_int32(int size,int threads)
{
//initialize index variables, random number generator, and timer
int i;
int size2D=size*size;
srand(SEED);
struct TIME_STRUCT start,end;

//allocate memory for matrices
INT32_TYPE *A=malloc(sizeof(INT32_TYPE)*(size*size));
INT32_TYPE *B=malloc(sizeof(INT32_TYPE)*(size*size));
INT32_TYPE *C=malloc(sizeof(INT32_TYPE)*(size*size));

//initialize input matrices to random numbers
//initialize output matrix to zeros
for(i=0;i<(size*size);i++)
{
    A[i]=rand();
    B[i]=rand();
    C[i]=0;
}

//serial operation
if(threads==1)
{
    //start timer
    TIME_GET(&start);
    //computation
    for(i=0;i<size2D;i++)
    {
        C[i]=A[i]/B[i];
    }
    //end timer
    TIME_GET(&end);
}
//parallel operation
else
{
    //start timer
    TIME_GET(&start);
    //parallelize with OpenMP
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads) private(i)
    //computation
    for(i=0;i<size2D;i++)
    {
        C[i]=A[i]/B[i];
    }
    //end timer
    TIME_GET(&end);
}

//free memory
free(C);
free(B);
free(A);

return TIME_RUNTIME(start,end);
```

}

Comment: Could you show some code, please?

Comment: Could you show some [_minimal_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `B[i]` is ever 0, you'll get a divide by zero problem. `rand()` can return 0.

So sometimes `B[i]=rand();` will assign 0 to `B[i]`.

As stated in the comment, this will be more common with fewer bits as 0 is a more likely outcome of the `rand()` operation.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the int32 implementation never returns that error.

Comment: Never is a long time.  With low resolution (8 bit), I'd expect 0 to turn up more easily than with higher resolution.  If you run your 32 bit version often enough, without reseeding, you'll likely get a zero from your `rand()` function, then divide by 0.

Comment: Jup, 1 in 256 are decent odds, 1 in 2.147.483.647... not so much